# How to assign a value from an address to a pointer on the go?

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, scanf

Causes a segmentation fault:

```
int n;
int *variable = scanf("%d",&n);
printf("Printing :%d",*variable);
```

No problem:

```
int n;
scanf("%d",&n);
int *variable = &n;
printf("Printing :%d",*variable);
```

How to achieve the first one without the segmentation fault?

Comment: `variable` is a int pointer but you are storing a integer in it.

Comment: This code should not compile, since the line `int *variable = scanf("%d",&n);` is not valid C. Your compiler is likely mis-configured.

Comment: `scanf` returns the number of items successfully read, not the address of the thing being read into (which makes sense if you're reading into multiple items at once).  You *can* take the address of `n` before reading into it, though.

Comment: Improve grammar & tag & title

Comment: What should code do if the `scanf()` does not scan an `int` due to non-numeric input, end-of-file or input error?

Comment: Why is the goal to return an `int *` and not an `int`?  Otherwise code could use `int variable = (scanf("%d",&n) == 1 ? n : some_default_value);` or the like.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `scanf` was successful, it *returns* 1 (in general it returns the number of variables that were set).

In your second snippet you discard that (useful) information, and you are setting a pointer `varaible` to the address of `n`, which is perfectly valid. (If `scanf` returned 0 then `n` would be uninitialised, and the behaviour of your `printf` call *undefined*.)

In the first snippet you set a *pointer* to the `int` constant `0` or `1` depending on the return value of `scanf`. That's fine too, but the behaviour on *dereferencing* that pointer with

```
*variable
```

is *undefined*.

If you want to be flashy, and have a robust conversation with your code reviewer, you could use the *expression separator operator* and write

```
int n;
int *variable = (scanf("%d",&n), &n);
```

but that's naughty since, again, you discard the return value of `scanf`, and `n` could be uninitialised.

Comment: I think the last example goes too far beyond the OPs C knowledge and may confuse him. He needs to learn what is the pointer, what is the refernced object and how to allocate the memory for it

Comment: @P__J__: We need to stop assuming that all (if any perhaps) answers are targetted solely at the OP. This is a Q & A site not a forum for folk needing help although the latter is a corollary. Let's not get into the habit of submitting answers that pertain to some kind of lowest common denominator. Above all, let's not patronise the OP.

Comment: `&(scanf("%d",&n), n)` doesn't look valid.  The comma operator in C doesn't evaluate to an lvalue.

Comment: I suspect you wanted `int *variable = &(scanf("%d",&n), &n);`  (& added)

Comment: @chux Think that might be correct now, although I can’t check for sure right now.

Comment: `&scanf("%d",&n), &n;` did not compile for me.  "error: lvalue required as unary '&' operand"

Comment: @chux I think it should be `int *variable = (scanf("%d",&n), &n);`

Comment: @dbush [That](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51823955/how-to-assign-a-value-from-an-address-to-a-pointer-on-the-go/51824022?noredirect=1#comment90643274_51824022) looks good.  How about `int *variable = (scanf("%d",&n) == 1 ? &n : NULL);` to detect valid input?

Comment: @chux Even better.

Comment: @chux Can you fix this for me pretty please? My wife is about to have a baby!

Answer (score 1):

`scanf("%d",&n);` returns integer not pointer to integer. Below is the prototype of scanf.

```
int scanf(const char *format, ...);
```

When you point like below you are actually pointing to invalid address and it will lead to undefined behavior.

```
int *variable = scanf("%d",&n);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you declare and initialize the pointer you assign the value to the pointer itself. The `*` is needed to show the compiler that you are declaring the pointer to the object of some type not the object itself

When you use the `*` later in the code you dereference that pointer.

```
void foo(void)
{
   int a;
   int *b = &a;     //you assign the pointer `b` itself - no dereferencing

   *b = 5;          //you dereference the pointer and asssign the the referenced object
}
```

The "fresh" declared pointer (unless initialized with the reference to the valid object) does not point to the valid object and its dereferencing invokes the Undefined Behavior

```
void foo(void)
{
   int a;
   int *b = &a;     //b is pointing to the valid object -> the variable `a`
   int *c;     //c is not pointing to valid object
   int *d;     //d is not pointing to valid object

   c = malloc(sizeof(*c));     //now c is pointing to the valid object (if malloc has not failed of course)
   *c = 5      // correct no UB
   *d = 5;         // incorrect - UB


   *b = 5;          //correct no UB 
}
```

the syntax is similar (the `*` before the pointer name) but it does something completely different. I have noticed that it is a bit confusing for the beginners